# remove app padding when app in landscape mode

Tags: flutter, landscape

i've created absolutely new app and i replaced main method by

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);

  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);

  await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.immersive,
    overlays: [],
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

[image]
and i have black line on the left side and i don't know how to remove it.
PS
tried all values in setEnabledSystemUIMode

Comment: Have you tried it in real device or an different emulator?

Comment: it's a real device, i just use scrcpy to display the phone screen on the monitor

Comment: Can you share code of MyApp Widget?

Comment: it is just app created with F1 -> flutter:  New Project